# Update a cx_freeze exe without repeating the setup process

Tags: tkinter, exe, cx-freeze

Simple question - If I was to change my python code, what would be the quickest way to update the exe file? (Such as updating the python file directly, if that is an option).
Thanks!

Comment: If it is like `py2exe`, it keeps a log so you could try and update that and then the exe (I'm not quite sure how though :-(

Comment: cx_freeze stands literally for freezing the binaries, I'd think you'd need to convert from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just changing the script, no external files that were needed previously then you would just compile again (there is no other way):

```
setup.py build
```

A faster method would be to build a bash (Linux) or batch (Windows) file to run the compilation automatically.

Batch file example:

```
setup.py build
```

Just double press to run.

PowerShell example:

```
./setup.py build
```

Right click and select run.

You could also add `pause` at the end for debugging purposes.

Bash example:

```
python3.6 setup.py build
```

Comment: Hmm. Is there a better alternative to cx_freeze that would allow for easier updates?

Comment: @Chris Pyinstaller or cx_Freeze, that's it really.  Pyinstaller might be easier using a bash/batch script since it uses the command line mainly.  Either way you would need to recompile everything anyway.